# List of functions known to pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For some reason, I was unable to find out which functions are known by pgf. Of course, I was reading the manual, but all I could find there were examples. So I am wondering if it is known which functions are known, and perhaps also what their peculiarities are (e.g. `sin` expects the argument to be in degrees, but `sinh` does not).

Comment: They are in the TikZ/PGF manual

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See chapter 89, in particular section 89.3, in the manual for TikZ/`pgf`, version 3.0.1a (the latest stable version at the moment).

You can find the manual by opening a terminal/command prompt and entering `texdoc pgf`. That will open the documentation for the version of `pgf` that is installed in your TeX distribution.

If you can't make that work, find the manual at [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) or [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

[image: screenshot from manual]

As usual in the manual, the functions listed on the page from which that screenshot is taken, are hyperlinks, so click on one to jump to its description. Or just scroll further down that chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking at the wrong places...

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to the manual you're referring to? There are several different versions on the net...

Comment: Open a terminal/command prompt on your computer, and type `texdoc pgf`. Then you'll get the documentation included with your TeX distribution. Which, if you have a somewhat recent distribution, will give you the manual for version 3.0.1a, the latest stable version. Or see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @marmot Oops, forgot pinging you in my previous comment. Anyways, updated answer as well.

Comment: @marmot Google "pgf ctan" and you will have the newest official version...

Comment: Thanks a lot! And @Dr.ManuelKuehner : thanks! (I found it, but I thought that this is a very useful answer which will live for some time, after which the functions are no longer in chapter 89.3 but somewhere else. That's the reason why I was suggesting a link.)

Comment: The search term " Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: " in the manual may be helpful.